# Angular 2 :Delete child component on clicking close button in respective component

Tags: angular

> This is my parent.html

```
parent.html 
<h1>Test for dynamic component</h1>
<button (click)="addBox('BoxOneComponent')">AddBoxOne</button>
<button (click)="addBox('BoxTwoComponent')">AddBoxTwo</button>
<div>
  <ng-template #parent></ng-template>
</div>
```

> And here is the component of it .

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit,OnInit {
  @ViewChild('parent',{read:ViewContainerRef}) parent;

  public resolve;

  constructor(private cfr:ComponentFactoryResolver){}

  addBox(val){
    let data;
    switch(val){
      case "BoxOneComponent":
        data = BoxOneComponent;
        break;
      case "BoxTwoComponent":
        data = BoxTwoComponent;
        break;
    }
    this.resolve = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(data);
    this.parent.createComponent(this.resolve);
  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }


  ngAfterContentInit(){

  }

}
```

> this is my child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'box-one',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="delete()">Close</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div{
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      background-color:yellow;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    button{
      margin-left:50px;
    }
  `]
})
export class BoxOneComponent  {


}
```

I am able to add component dynamically . Now i want to delete the child component dynamically on clicking the button close present in the respective child component. I know that we have to use ViewContainerRef.remove(index of child). But how to get the index of child component in reference to parent ?

Demo : [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppsnoe)

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic component needs to somehow notify the parent component that it should be removed. The simplest way I can think of for doing this is providing an Obseravble (a Promise would work too) in the component instance that the parent can subscribe to.

For type safety, you could also create an interface for those components (specifying that they must have a `close$` obsevable inside).

---

## Boxes

```
<button (click)="close()">Close</button>

public close$ = new Subject<void>()
public close() {
  this.close$.next(null)
}
```

## Parent

```
const cmp: ComponentRef<any> = this.parent.createComponent(this.resolve);
cmp.instance.close$.take(1).subscribe(() => cmp.destroy())
```

---

Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mznyud?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks , And i have a doubt . How to get the index of the child's component in reference to parent ?

Comment: Why do you need the index? Your question was how to remove them.

Comment: If i have a remove button for child component in the parent's component .I would need an index of the child to destroy it right ?

Comment: No. I have shown you a demo that removes the components without need for an index. Did you read my answer?

Comment: Yeah gone through it !

Comment: I have provided a working demo at the end of the answer that does what you wanted: it removes the component when you click on the "close" button. I do not understand why are you asking me now for the index when it's not needed.

Comment: I just have a doubt , whether is it possible to get the index of child component ? Cause i thought of doing it in that way. Never knew that it could be done in your way .